# Spring @JsonProperty on Setter ignored

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to get a json from a POJO. I only want to get the Json on the setter (in order to set a collection of object).

I have a **Company** class with a set of **Employee**. 
When I set the collection of employee on the company object, I am expecting to see the collection on the Json Object produced by ObjectMapper. But it's not working.

Here my code and the problem

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    //-------------------
    // PROPERTY
    //-------------------

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name = "COMPANY_EMPLOYEE",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employees_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();


    //-------------------
    // GETTER AND SETTER
    //-------------------

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}

//------ In Main Application

Company company = new Company();
        company.setName("Company");
        //etc....... company properties

Employee employee = new Employee();
         employee.setFirstName("FirstName");
        //etc....... employee properties

//Create the set of employee
Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<>();
              employeeSet.add(employee);

//Add the list/set of employee to the company      
company.setEmployees(employeeSet);

//Expect to have the employee set here but it's empty...
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 System.out.println(new String(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(company)));
```

**Update:**

I followed this article that explains the [async mechanism of JsonIgnore with JsonProperty](http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/). (Which is exactly what I want)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try  putting the JsonProperty on the  employees member like this.

@JsonProperty
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

Comment: I tried and have this: java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration

Comment: You have `@JsonIgnore` on the field so whatever you put on the accessors is ignored.

Comment: Nope, actually it is how it should works if you want to have an async mechanism (just deserialization for example)